# Read s2p Z parameter files in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to read s2p files in using Python scikit-rf library. The s2p file in not in S parameter. I converted it to Z parameter. Looks like scikit-rf can read only S parameter file. Is there any other library or way to read s2p files with Z parameter. Below is how I am reading the file:

```
import skrf as rf

ntwk = rf.Network('ZTEST5_SHORTED.s10p')
s = ntwk.s
print(s)
```

Below is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pujai\PycharmProjects\SIIntegration\practice.py", line 26, in <module>
    ntwk = rf.Network('ZTEST5_SHORTED_DCfitted.s10p')
  File "C:\Users\pujai\PycharmProjects\SIIntegration\venv\lib\site-packages\skrf\network.py", line 457, in __init__
    self.read_touchstone(filename, self.encoding)
  File "C:\Users\pujai\PycharmProjects\SIIntegration\venv\lib\site-packages\skrf\network.py", line 2050, in read_touchstone
    raise NotImplementedError('only s-parameters supported for now.')
NotImplementedError: only s-parameters supported for now.
```

If I try to read an S parameter file, it works fine. Any help?